# file compression to handle intermediary output in c++

Tags: c++

I want to compress a intermediate output of my program ( in C++) and then decompress it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fastest c++ file compression library available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124239/fastest-c-file-compression-library-available)

Comment: Why not use zlib ? Light, efficient and very widely used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Boost IOStreams to compress your data, for example something along these lines to compress/decompresses into/from a file (example adapted from [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html)):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>    
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>

namespace bo = boost::iostreams;

int main() 
{
    {
    std::ofstream ofile("hello.gz", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
    bo::filtering_ostream out;
    out.push(bo::gzip_compressor()); 
    out.push(ofile); 
    out << "This is a gz file\n";
    }

    {
    std::ifstream ifile("hello.gz", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    bo::filtering_streambuf<bo::input> in;
    in.push(bo::gzip_decompressor());
    in.push(ifile);
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, std::cout);
    }
}
```

You can also have a look at Boost Serialization - which can make saving your data much easier. It is possible to combine the two approaches ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753469/how-to-hook-up-boost-serialization-iostreams-to-serialize-gzip-an-object-to)). IOStreams support `bzip` compression as well.

**EDIT:** To address your last comment - you can compress an existing file... but it would be better to write it as compressed to begin with. If you really want, you could tweak the following code:

```
std::ifstream ifile("file", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
std::ofstream ofile("file.gz", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);

bo::filtering_streambuf<bo::output> out;
out.push(bo::gzip_compressor());
out.push(ofile); 
bo::copy(ifile, out);
```

Comment: That was of great help. How do I serve the location of the file I want to compress instead of text ? Thanks

Comment: @user1309369: Can you clarify? Do you have an existing file that you want to compress? Or?

Comment: I want to compress an existing file and then decompress it when I need it in original format.